# Call to undefined function dbtrim()

Tags: php

I have a form for login and I catch the posted data with ajax. Then post it to logincheck.php. It calls functions from db.php and db.php is included in the first line of my index.php but after I started to use ajax, it started to give error like;

> Fatal error:  Call to undefined function dbtrim() in D:\xampp\htdocs\include\logincheck.php on line 6

I'm a newbie to PHP and know basic coding. So please explain me in detailed whats wrong with that. Thank you..

Here is how I call the function from logincheck.php;

```
if($_POST) {

    $KullaniciAdi = strip_tags(trim(dbtrim($_POST["KullaniciAdi"])));
    $Sifre = strip_tags(trim(dbtrim($_POST["sifre"])));
```

DB.php function;

```
function dbtrim($par) {
    return str_replace(array("'","\""), array("'","&quot;"), $par);
}
```

Ajax code;

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 


$(function(){
 $("#btnGiris").click(function(){
  var $txtKullaniciAdi = $('.KullaniciAdi');
  var $txtSifre = $('.sifre');
  
  if ($txtKullaniciAdi.val().trim().length == 0) {
   $('.sonuc').fadeIn(200).addClass("hata").html("");
   $('.sonuc').html("<b>Kullanıcı adını boş bırakamazsınız..</b>");
  } else if ($txtSifre.val().trim().length == 0) {
   $('.sonuc').fadeIn(200).addClass("hata").html("");
   $('.sonuc').html("<b>Şifreyi boş bırakamazsınız..</b>");
  } else {
   var veriler = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param({ KullaniciAdi: $txtKullaniciAdi.val(), Sifre: $txtSifre.val() });
   
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "include/logincheck.php",
   data: veriler,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data){
    if(data.Sonuc == "Hata1"){
     $('.sonuc').fadeIn(200).addClass("hata").html("");
     $('.sonuc').html(data.Mesaj)
    } else if(data.Sonuc == "Hata2"){
     $('.sonuc').fadeIn(200).addClass("hata").html("");
     $('.sonuc').html(data.Mesaj)
    } else {
     location.reload();
    }
   },
   error: function (xmlHttpRequest, status, err) {
    alert(xmlHttpRequest.statusText + ' ' + xmlHttpRequest.status + ' : ' + xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
   }
  });
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The error simply means the `dbtrim` function you call in your logincheck.php page isn't standard, and isn't defined anywhere in your code. Have you missed an include?

Comment: As I say, I included db.php in the first line of my index.php, java is also there in index.php and it posts the data to logincheck.php. Then I get that error.

Comment: Is the path in the include correct?

Comment: They are in the same directory.

Comment: I've removed JavaScript tags again. PHP and JavaScript are entirely different languages that (in this case) won't even run on the same computer. An *undefined function* server-side PHP fatal error cannot be caused by client-side Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `logincheck.php` file you should include the `DB.php` so that the functions defined inside `DB.php` can be use.

You can do that by adding this code below at the top of DB.php file.

```
<?php include("DB.php"); ?>
```

[Here's](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/include-files/) a good reference about using PHP `include`

Comment: Then I get that error cause its already included in index.php's first line.

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare idval() (previously declared in D:\xampp\htdocs\db.php:51) in D:\xampp\htdocs\db.php on line 54

Comment: @AlperKöse Do `include_once` instead. `<?php include_once("DB.php"); ?>`

Comment: Still the same error, but I realized that If I include db.php only in logincheck.php, it gives errors but not because the function. I may go somewhere from that but why I cannot call that function when I included it in index.php?

Comment: @AlperKöse The structure is bit confusing. The Ajax code sits inside `index.php`?

Comment: Yes its inside in index.php

Comment: @AlperKöse And inside `giriskontrol.php` is where you included `logincheck.php`?

Comment: I'm sorry I just mistyped that. Before I post it here, I renamed giriskontrol.php as logincheck.php so people can understand. Here is my structure;

In index.php, I have javascript. Javascript post data to logincheck.php and logincheck.php uses a function from db.php. DB.php is included in the first line of index.php. Then I get that error

Comment: @AlperKöse Ok that's weird. Are you preventing the default action of the form when submitted? Something like this: `$('form').on('submit', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); // then ajax code lies here });`

Answer (score 0):

search "`function dbtrim`" in your project, than `include_once` the file may help you.